# Installing Ext JS 4 - Where to put files?

Tags: extjs, rendering, installation

Hi to all from Córdoba !. My question would be the following one... How to configure my Ext JS 4 files so as to start working ?. Coz although I manage to show a window, the close button when I put: "closable: true" doesn't appear or for instance when I put "frame:true" the window doesn't show a frame and the title bar is all white... So it is a little bit weird !. I would like to know If someone can explain me in which folders I should place all the css, js and png or jpg files in order to have a correct rendering of the widgets or maybe if someone could upload somewhere an ext js 4 project with all the files it would be ok (the entire ext js library I would prefere) !...
For example: My project structure would be:

1. resources

   1. css
   2. sass
   3. themes
2. extjs

   1. ext-all-debug.js
3. index.html

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/ext-all.css">

   <script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-all-debug.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">

       Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL = 'resources/themes/images/default/tree/s.gif';
       Ext.onReady(function() {
           Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL =     'resources/themes/images/default/tree/s.gif';
       var win = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
           renderTo: document.body,
           title: 'Hello',
           height: 200,
           width: 400,
           draggable: true,
           frame: true,
           closable: true
           }).show();

       Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
           width: 400,
           height: 400,
           renderTo: document.body,
           items: [{
               title: 'Foo'
               }, {
               title: 'Bar',
               tabConfig: {
                   title: 'Custom Title',
                   tooltip: 'A button tooltip'
               }
           }]
        });        
   });
   </script>
   ```

   If someone sees something incorrect, pls tell me...

Comment: Simply take a look at the sencha learning page http://www.sencha.com/learn/extjs/?4x or the tons of examples that you get with the package...

Comment: First of all... Thankx for answering !. Well... I go straight to the point... I've done that but I haven't managed to put them right as it all seem not to render correctly... I've seen a lot of examples and analyze the code to see what files are included but I don't get the result... If I give you my email, would you send me a project to my inbox ?... Meanwhile, I am working with Ext JS 3.3.1 but I want to leave it and start working with Ext JS 4 as it has more features...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A summary of what is given at the [sencha](http://www.sencha.com/learn/getting-started-with-ext-js-4) website:

Your project structure should look like this:

- appname

  - app

    - namespace

      - Class1.js
      - Class2.js
      - ...
  - extjs
  - resources

    - css
    - images
    - ...
  - app.js
  - index.html

Mainly concentrate on extjs folder. That should be a copy of the folder that you receive from the sencha website. Don't change the files inside.

The minimum number of files required to run extjs are to be included in the following order:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello Ext</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/your/own/css/if/any">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="your/own/js.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

That's it! You're ready to Rock 'n Roll!

Instead of `ext-debug.js` you can use `ext-all-debug.js` - This file contains the entire Ext JS library. This can be helpful for shortening your initial learning curve, however ext-debug.js is preferred in most cases for actual application development.

Comment: I think I manage to solve the problem... But there is one more detail... When I show a Windows as I said, the close image from the upper right corner doesn't render... And also it seems that when I put frame false, the frame doesn't dissapear... Thankx for writing so much !!! yes ?...

Comment: It was quite simple as my Project is called "ExtJS v4.0 Practica Final" and there I put the "index.html" and the "extjs" folder with the js files and the resources folder that I obtained from Sencha... but well... There is that tiny problem I wan't to solve... Ext JS 4 is amazing !... Blessings !